# Why empty function changes the result?

Tags: glsl

I've got this glsl vertex shader:

```c
layout(location = 0) in vec4 a_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 a_color;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 v_color;

struct VertexMaterial
{
    vec4 color;
};

void InitMaterial(out VertexMaterial material)
{
    material.color = a_color;
}

void ExecuteVertexMaterial(out VertexMaterial material)
{
}

void main()
{
    VertexMaterial material;
    InitMaterial(material);

    {
        ExecuteVertexMaterial(material);
        v_color = material.color;
    }

    gl_Position = a_position;
}
```

`ExecuteVertexMaterial` function is empty, so I'd expect that `out VertexMaterial material` won't be changed.

But actually, the color starts flickering

https://youtu.be/GqRE0B0Nw50

when this funciton is commented out:

```c
void main()
{
    VertexMaterial material;
    InitMaterial(material);

    {
        //ExecuteVertexMaterial(material);
        v_color = material.color;
    }

    gl_Position = a_position;
}
```

or it executes `InitMaterial` function:

```c
void ExecuteVertexMaterial(out VertexMaterial material)
{
    InitMaterial(material);
}
```

it works as expected:

[image]

Why is that? Is there a way to have `ExecuteVertexMaterial()` function empty?

Comment: What is the point of having this function when is does nothing?

Comment: Body of the function will be fed by the user's code and I don't to force the user to call `InitMaterial()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#:%7E:text=A%20parameter%20declared%20as%20out,specified%20when%20calling%20the%20function.) article

> A parameter declared as `out` will not have its value initialized by the caller. The function will modify the parameter, and after the function's execution is complete, the value of the parameter will be copied out into the variable that the user specified when calling the function. Note that the initial value of the parameter at the start of the function being called is undefined, just as if one had simply created a local variable.

This means, that if you pass `material` to the function `ExecuteVertexMaterial(out VertexMaterial material)`, the initial value of `material` is undefined. The job of the function would be to set this out parameter properly. In your case, it doesn't do that. So it will overwrite the value of `material` with an undefined (random) value.

The article also explains the `in` and `inout` keywords.

> A parameter declared as `in` means that the value given to that parameter will be copied into the parameter when the function is called. The function may then modify that parameter as they see fit, but those changes will not affect the calling code.

> The `inout` declaration combines both. The parameter's value will be initialized by the value supplied by the user, and its final value will be output

So, in order to achieve your goal, you need to declare the parameter as `inout` to pass already definded values to the function and be able to change them additionally. If you don't want to change them by reference, it is sufficient to declare those parameters as `in` (default behaviour).

```
void ExecuteVertexMaterial(inout VertexMaterial material)
{
}
```